# How to stop a for loop in R and keep the data

Tags: r, for-loop

I have my code running in a for loop over dates. The code takes a while to run, and there a couple of days left, but I urgently need whatever results there are. Is there a way of breaking the code/for loop, but keep whatever data has been produced up to now.

Comment: We could write to a file with `write.table(x, "myX.txt", append = TRUE)` within the loop, then we do not have to stop R to see the file output.

Comment: Provide reproducible example, and show us the *for loop*, there might be a better way.

Comment: @zx8754 I think OP already has written and is running the loop, so it's too late to add extra code.

Comment: If I run `for(i in 1:100) {x = i; Sys.sleep(0.1)}` and interrupt the process with the escape key, the current value of `x` is preserved - which is very promising. However, sometimes with more complicated code when I press the escape key it crashes R...

Comment: Try setting the loop running on another computer and test what happens when you interrupt it and restart.

Comment: Yes, already written and running loop unfortunately. All good suggestions, however, and I'll definitely employ them in the future. I'm afraid if I break the loop it'll crash R as it is a long complicated script. I'll test your suggestion @Richard Telford thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can press "escape", examine the results and then restart your loop.

```
for(iii in 1:100000000) force(iii)
# now press ESC
iii
# in my case 1121673
# use this value to restart the loop later:
for(iii in 1121674:100000000) force(iii)
```

Comment: Will this work if the script inside the for loop is more complex than your above example do you think?

Comment: yes, the current value of the variable that is being looped over (in this case, `iii`) is always stored in the global environment (if you're not running your loop within a function). so yes, in a general case, you can stop and restart it. it is probably a good idea to restart at the same value, not the next one, however. (i.e. 1121673, not 1121674 in the example above)